# Android cannot excludeFromRecents if it's in the app is running

Tags: android, kotlin

I have added `android:excludeFromRecents` into `<activity/>` to hide my app from [Recents Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents#adding). But it's not working if I open Recents Screen when the app is **running**.

Here is details how I've tested:

*Case 1:* Open my app -> Go back to main screen -> Click square button (Open Recents Screen) -> Do not see my app **=> Its working fine**

*Case 2:* Open my app -> Click square button -> My app is there **=> It's not working**

My question is:

- Why this happen?
- Is there any way to completely hide my app from Recents Screen? (Note: I don't want to kill/finish the app, only hide)

Answer (score 0):

Yes to work around this issue, just set these two flags in onPause() / onStop() or handle whatever way you want but these flags must be set

```
 getIntent().addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)
 getIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)    
 finish()
```

Comment: I have change the ques for more specific. I don't wanna kill the app. And the flags seem not working without ```finish()```.

Comment: Try adding these flags in onCreate()